# PHP session with permissions

Tags: php, session, permissions

I am having problem with the code.

It suppose to allow admin to view only admin page

and user to view user page only.

my admin still able to view user page.

below is my landing page

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    include("config.php");
    $host = "localhost"; //DB host 
$username = "root";  //DB Username 
$password = ""; //DB Password 
$db_name = "hklcanet_pha"; //DB Name 
$tbl_name = "users"; //Table name, where users are stored 
$dbconfig = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);



$username = $_POST['username']; //Get username from login form 
$password = $_POST['password']; //Get password from login form 

$username = stripslashes($username); //Makes string safe 
$password = stripslashes($password); //Makes string safe 
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconfig, $username); //Makes string safer 
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconfig, $password); //Makes string safer 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'"; //SQL Query 
$result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql); //Executes Query 

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); //Count rows selected (1 if a username/password combo can be found) 

if($rows == 1){ 
        session_start(); //Starts a PHP session 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //Allows $username to be used later 
            header("location: interphase1.php");
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        { 
        $permissions = $row['permissions']; //Gets the permissions of the user 
        $id = $row['id']; //Gets the ID of the user 
        } 
        $_SESSION['permissions'] = $permissions; //Allows $permissions to be used later 
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id; //Allows $id to be used later 
        $_SESSION['authenticated'] = 1; //Allows $id to be used later 

echo("Login Succesful");//Prints success message 
} 
else  
{ 
//echo("Invalid Username/Password"); 
} 
?>
```

user page

```
    <?php
session_start(); 
$permissions = $_SESSION['permissions']; 
   if($_SESSION['authenticated'] != 1) 
   { 
   echo("You must be logged in"); 
   header("location:landing.php");
   } 
   else 
   { 
   if($permissions < 0) 
      { 

      header("location:quicksummary.php");
      echo("Your permissions are not high enough");
      } 
   } 

?>
```

admin page

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$permissions = $_SESSION['permissions']; 
   if($_SESSION['authenticated'] != 1) 
   { 
   header("location:landing.php");
   echo("You must be logged in"); 

   } 
   else 
   { 
   if($permissions < 1 ) 
      { 
      header("location:quicksummary.php");
      echo("Your permissions are not high enough");

      } 
   } 

?>
```

thanks and appreciate if somebody can help me on this, still new with the PHP code.

Comment: $permissions < 0 means? How many possible values do u have against $permissions

Comment: Sorry , In my database permission admin : 1 , user: 0

Comment: And r u getting all values in $_SESSION, can u share the result of print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: R u redirect to header("location:landing.php");???

Comment: If authentication = null , yes it will redirect to landing page (login page)

Comment: First of all print_r($row) inside the while than chk your session is working or not

Comment: don't you think `header("location: interphase1.php");` will redirect you to `interphase1.php` without executing next lines ?

Comment: what should i do, if i want user page appear when $permissions = 0 and admin page appear when $permissions =1

Comment: Plz add @devpro when u comment, plz chk your query result first

Comment: Than chk $_SESSION values if both fine than we will move on conditions